# How to use role playing date dimensions in Tableau?

Tags: sql, database, date, join, tableau-api

So I am connecting my data-warehouse to Tableau to make various reports for our business users. The database follows a star schema. I have several typical dimensions as User information, orders, ....,date dimensions etc. I want to create a view(text table) containing certain business KPIs on a weekly basis (for last 12 weeks)

My date dimension is a role playing dimension- i.e It can refer to order date or customer sign-up date or customer membership joining date or shipping date etc. How do I make sure that the correct dates are referred for each entry in my text-table? Example:

**Week No**.                **June29    July6   July13  July20  July27**
Total Members
New Members
Active Members
Purchasing Members
1st Time buyers
Conversion %

"New Members" will be calculated on the basis of customer signup date within the given date range. Similarly Purchasing members will be calculated from the order table by counting numbers of users who placed orders within given date range. How do I make sure that the dates correspond to the dates in the individual tables? (Each table may have multiple date colums such as signup date, unsubscribed date etc.)
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

That depends highly on how your tables are structured. If I understand correctly you have an events oriented db, i.e., each entry is an event. You have a single column for date, and one column to identify the event (and a lot of other fields).

If that is correct, here are some tips to achieve what you want:

1) Total members. Try using Running Total (table calculation) of COUNTD(user_id). This way you'll have the number of different user_ids to date.

2) New members. Filter for "registration event" and use COUNTD()

3) Active members. What does this mean? But logic is the same, filter for the right event and use COUNTD()

4) Purchasing members. Filter for "purchase event" and use COUNTD() again

5) First time buyers. This is trickier if you don't have a "first purchase event". You need to create that event (and don't forget to include it on 4), or add some marker to identify a first purchase. It's not possible to do that in Tableau directly on that data source, as it would need a table calculation to check what was the first purchase (if any)

6) Conversion. Depends on how you calculate it. Can be as simple as [[First time buyers] / [New members]. But you can have different definitions or time frames (like # first time buyers over new members of the last 6 months)

Try some of this, and if you can't do something, or your database is not actually like I understood, describe it better, show what you have tried, what you got as a result and what you expected as a result

Comment: Thanks. Unfortunately i don't have enough points to attach an image or workbook....The thing is I am able to get the numbers for each event type separately .... (on separate tableau sheets), but not in a SINGLE table. If I put dates on the top row of my table, Tableau doest know whether this date refers to signup date or membership start date etc. (Currently everything is getting sliced according to signup date...)

Comment: Man, unless those quantities you're trying to calculate are MECE (mutually exclusive, complementary exhaustive, http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MECE_principle), you can't plot all of them in a single table. Rather, you'll have to plot them in individual sheets and then put them in a dashboard

Comment: Umm...well they arent MECE....so....oh well, I tried :/ 
Thanks though, I can move on...